# PHP code showing in browser

Tags: php, browser

I have some PHP code in my .php file which is showing as it is in the browser. As in, I want the code to execute on form submit, but its showing as plain text in the browser.

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['ss-submit']))//submit button name
  {

 //Describing the Leads object and printing the array
 $describe = $connection->describeSObjects(array('Lead'));
 print_r($describe);
 ?>
```

Below it is an HTML form which displays correctly.

now this .php file is included in a .tpl file.

Comment: I may be wrong, but if you're including a PHP file in to a tpl file then the PHP isn't going to execute, including a tpl file in to a PHP file however will work.

Comment: How do you include this php ? Which template engine are you using ?

Comment: Is tpl going to be interpreted? If then check it may be escaping those

Comment: By the way, PHP should be placed in your controllers if you are using an MVC framework. No need to try to include it in your templates. It's actually PHP that "loads" your template. Not the opposite

Comment: I am using smarty.... and Karl's comment is indeed useful but doesnt provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your both files different.
In case of smarty the php file is executed first process data and then with the help of assign function you can assign your output from php to the tpl file.

Try as much as you can process data at the php page only

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['ss-submit']))//submit button name
  {
  //Describing the Leads object and printing the array
  $describe = $connection->describeSObjects(array('Lead'));
  $smarty->assign('lead_array',$describe);
 ?>
```

1. Replace $smarty with your smarty object
2. Replace lead_array with a name with which you want to access array in .tpl file

now on the .tpl page you can simply write

```
{$lead_array|print_r}
```

make sure your form on the .tpl page post on the same php file

it will print your array

This is a sure solution try it once and you will get desired output.

Answer (score 0):

in a .htaccess file

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .tpl
```

beware this parses all tpl files as if they were php. A templating engine may be better